# OAuth 2 requires a redirect uri, what would that be for windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0, uri-scheme

I have just realised that OAuth 2 authentication requires a redirect uri to send some refresh tokens back to. I have no idea what uri I should be using for windows phone 8. I have seen something about uri scheme? Does anyone know what has got to be done?

I have placed

```
"http://localhost/"
```

as the redirect uri as this blokey does

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net-social/blob/master/examples/Spring.OAuth2WindowsPhoneQuickStart/Spring.OAuth2WindowsPhoneQuickStart/App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

You should normally try to avoid storing any secrets on a device. Using the "implicit flow" instead with signed tokens.

See this example: https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.Windows8.Cs/blob/master/Auth0Client/Auth0Client.cs or this one specifically for Win Phone 8: https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.WindowsPhone/blob/master/Auth0Client/Auth0Client.cs

> Note: the `client secret` in those examples is used for something else.

The `callback` is just a URL that the browser in your app (the `endUri` parameter in  `WebAuthenticationBroker` if using Win8) will recognize as the "end of the flow". "localhost" will do if your code recognizes it as the completion of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks mate, so actually, I do this, I make a call to an external API with a username and password typed in by user. It gets an access token and all that stuff and then I am ready to make a call to the api... only the authorized requests to make api calls require the redirect uri.. and I was thinking "I have no idea what that is or how to pretend it is" on the phone. I started to think I have to redirect through the web browser ui control that comes with vs, so I could get a response from it. I thought it sounded like a terrible way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, it's terrible :-) What service are you using for AuthN? not all of them support sending user credentials, and are meant to be used by web clients (the reason people embed a WebView in an app). Microsoft's WebAuthetnictationBroker is the acceptance of this technique.

Comment: Unfortunately the supplied c#.net classes built by the company serving the api do not have assemblies for windows phone 8, so I've gone ahead and started to write a set of re-usable classes with repositories bla bla... However, this is my first attempt at a win phone 8 app. I am by profession a PHP dev, but have recently discovered (as a hobby) c#.net mvc 4.0 and one thing led to another, i'm now doing some funky phone jazz. You can see why I am massively lost at the moment with what to do. I will check this out when I get back from work... I imagine this will need a few beers to get working.

Comment: The namespace for the Webapplication broker doesn't seem to exist for windows phone 8 apps

Comment: No, that's why I put the second link (WinPhone specific)

Comment: Fwiw, both links are dead now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me **urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob**